# How to solve this program?

Tags: java, if-statement

I found this Java exercise :

Create a class Sales that has TotalSales (double) , Commission (double),
Commissi onRate (double), and NoOfItems (integer).

write a java application that asks the user to enter the Total Sales and the number of items then calculates the commission and prints it out.
The commission rate should be as following:

Condition :

Less than 500, commissionRate is 0

Greater than or equal 500 or Number of Items >= 5, commission rate is 5%.

Grater than or equal 1000 or Number of items >=10, commission rate is 10%

..

I wrote this code:

---

Main Class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testSales {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sales s1 = new Sales();
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total Sales");
        s1.totalSale = get.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Items");
        s1.NoOfItems = get.nextInt();

        if(s1.totalSale < 500){
            s1.commission = s1.commissionRate = 0;
        }
        else if(s1.totalSale >= 500 && s1.totalSale <= 999 || s1.NoOfItems >= 5 && s1.NoOfItems <=9){
            s1.commission = s1.commissionRate = s1.totalSale * 5 / 100;
        }else if(s1.totalSale >= 1000 || s1.NoOfItems >=10) {
            s1.commission = s1.commissionRate = s1.totalSale *10/100;
        }
        System.out.println(s1.commission);

    }           
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the error (if any)?

Comment: 'but it doesn't seem like it works fine' - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the point brought up by HedonicHedgehog, there are a few other things to consider:

The sales class only has two global variables, which corresponds to the information entered by the user.  The other two fields, commission and commissionRate, are calculated values.  Therefore, there is no need to create variables for them.  Just add to the sales class accessor methods (getters) that return these values.  For example, below is my `getCommission()` method:

```
public double getCommission()
{
    return totalSales * getCommissionRate();
}
```

Of course, you can see this method is dependent upon the `getCommissionRate()` method. Because there is a gap on your requirements with total items, I am ignoring it for now:

```
public double getCommissionRate()
{
    if (totalSales < 500)
        return 0;
    if(totalSales < 1000)
        return .05;
    else
        return 0.1;
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a LOCAL `commission` variable, and set the value before returning it.  It is a good programming practice to limit the scope of your variables. In this case, there is not a good reason to have  a global `commission` or `commissionRate` variables.

Lastly, your test class is simplified because all you need to do is to prompt the user for the two needed fields, and it simply spits out the output because the Sales class provides the calculation needed to figure out the rest:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sales s1 = new Sales();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter total Sales");
    s1.setTotalSales(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Enter number of Items: ");
    s1.setNumOfItems(input.nextInt());

    System.out.printf("$%.2f", s1.getCommission());
    input.close();
}
```

I used the printf() method to format the output string.  The following is a sample run:

```
Enter total Sales: 503.45
Enter number of Items: 5
$25.17

Enter total Sales: 1003.67
Enter number of Items: 19
$100.37

Enter total Sales: 45.00
Enter number of Items: 19
$0.00
```

Remember that this example ignores the number of items because of the reasons already mentioned.  Once you figure out what needs to be done to cover of the gap in the requirements, you can modify this code to do the rest.  Also remember that your Sales class only requires two fields: totalSales and numOfItems. The other to components (commission, and commissionRate) are calculated; therefore, no global variable or setter methods needed.  Just the two getter methods I provided.

Answer (score 4):

One problem in your code is the case where NoOfItems > 5 but totalSale < 500. For this case, the commission will incorrectly be set to 0 because the first if statement eats it.

Please try to be more specific with your question. "this doesn't work and I don't know why" is not easy to help with.

Comment: I was about to point out the same thing. There are gaps in the requirements (business rules).